# Block windows button in full screen

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I use Windows 10 Pro.
I like to play pc games and I hate getting interrupted when I accidentally push the windows button. I got a Autohotkey script that looks like that:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

LWin::Return
RWin::Return
```

It works when I use applications in normal mode but when I start a game in full screen the windows button works normally again (which I don't want). How can that be? I also used a sofdtware called WinKill v0.3 and noticed the same behavior (works fine except when gaming in full screen mode).

Edit: the autohotkey script did actually work until recently but I have no idea what could have changed.

Comment: This works for me. Maybe you press Win + some other key?

Comment: I actually pressed the windows button on purpose in game once to test it and got that behavior. So it's not win + some key. However the script did work until recently but I have no idea what has changed.